# How to convert type of cv:Mat

Tags: c++, opencv

I tried the following way. Using convertTo function from uchar to CV_32SC1

```
imgCanny.convertTo(imgCanny32, CV_32SC1);
```

Which just gives me a blank imageCanny32.

The following way yields the same result.

```
imgCanny32 = Matrix(imgCanny.size(), CV_32SC1);

for (int i = 0;i < imgCanny.size().height;i++)
            for (int j = 0;j < imgCanny.size().width;j++)
                imgCanny32.at<int>(i,j) = imgCanny.at<uchar>(i,j);
```

I can't think of any other way.

Comment: "blank" in what sense? The one where you verified that each pixel is 0? Or the one where you fed the result to [`imshow`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html?highlight=imshow#imshow) and it **looks** all black?

Comment: The one where I do imshow and its all black.

Comment: OK, in that case it's clear :) Do read the documentation, and don't believe in your eyes in situations like this. (even if you were able to display 16bit grayscale, you wouldn't be able to discern the differences involved here). See my answer for further info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you describe it, you begin with an 8-bit one channel image. This means that each pixel is represented by an unsigned byte and as such can have a value between 0 and 255 inclusive.

Next, you perform a [`cv::Mat::convertTo`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-convertto), using the default values for `alpha` and `beta`. This means that in the new `Mat`, each pixel is represented by a signed 32-bit integer, but the values will remain in the 0-255 inclusive range.

Finally, you pass this `Mat` to the [`cv::imshow`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html?highlight=imshow#imshow) function. Notice the documentation:

> If the image is 16-bit unsigned or 32-bit integer, the pixels are
>   divided by 256. That is, the value range [0,255*256] is mapped to
>   [0,255].

Since the maximum pixel value the input image contains is 255, and the pixels are divided by 256, the image displayed by the function will appear all black.

---

That said, both ways of conversion you show are correct, although I'd prefer `convertTo`, since it will be optimized. If you want to display the `CV_32SC1` images, perhaps you should apply an appropriate scaling factor (`alpha = 256`) for the conversion.